# Getting wireless strength signal in C++

Tags: c++, wifi, powerpc, wii

I would like to create a little C/C++ program that should be able to detect wireless APs and getting from this some infos, like ID, the strength of the signal ... encryption (open, WPA, WEP) ... stuff like this! Like airodump or network stumbler!

This code will be run in a power PC, a console (Wii).

Anyone can help me posting some examples or tutorials?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is OS dependent, you need to look at the documentation of the OSes you want to run your program on. The language is pretty much irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Talk to the user WinterMute, here on Stack. He's the maintainer of devkitPro, for the NDS/Wii/Gamecube/etc. (I'm assuming you're using his toolchain and libraries...) He'll get you pointed in the right direction.

I'm working on DS programming with devkitPro, and honestly, he has an example packaged with devkitPro that's exactly this, but for the DS. He should have one for Wii as well.

Comment: You should go over to gbadev.org occasionally then as well if you do DS stuff.

Comment: I've been a member over there for a while, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shotgun! Very helpfull!
I'll keep in contact with WinterMute :)